# Disable token expiration in Owin

Tags: c#, asp.net, owin

I have a web app with `Owin` currently with 24 hours session expiration time:

```
AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0);
```

But now I wan't to disable the token expiration, I tried with this:

```
AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
```

But this gives me an exception on runtime (maybe `Owin` at some point adds a `DateTime` to this `TimeSpan.MaxValue` so an exception occurs). So I then tried this:

```
AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.MaxValue - TimeSpan.FromDays(365*10);
```

But still getting the same exception:

```
Application_Error: The added or subtracted value results in an un-representable DateTime.
Parameter name: value
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: The added or subtracted value results in an un-representable DateTime.
Parameter name: value
   at System.DateTime.AddTicks(Int64 value)
   at System.DateTimeOffset.Add(TimeSpan timeSpan)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthAuthorizationServerHandler.<InvokeTokenEndpointAsync>d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthAuthorizationServerHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsMiddleware.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContextStage.<RunApp>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.<DoFinalWork>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.Infrastructure.ErrorState.Rethrow()
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult ar)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.EndFinalWork(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

How can I remove the token expiration time?

Comment: Why do you want to have an unlimited access token? This is a big security risk if someone were to get that access token.

Comment: Because the app is designed to work only locally, there is no internet connection at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to remove the expiration time on the access token as this is by nature intended to stop someone having unlimited access to your app. One way would be to set the expiration far off into the future or another would be to keep refreshing the access token at certain intervals (not recommended) as in this example:

[OAuth Bearer Access Token sliding expiration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29497200/oauth-bearer-access-token-sliding-expiration)